# unable to open log file in intellij

Tags: selenium, cucumber, log4j, log4j2

I was trying to use log4j2 in my properties, I have integrated it in my project without any issue and my log file is also being formed in root directory of the project. But, only issue is that I am not able to open it by Ideolog plugin which is default plugin to open log file in Inteliij. Please help me to find out correct log pattern so that my log file can be opened in Intellij. Also,Please help me to modify my log4j2.properties file code in such a way so that I can generate logs in both HTML as well as log format.

Here is the code of my log4j2.properties file:-

```
//name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.file.append=true

loggers=file
logger.file.name=Demo
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Here is the console logs after my execution:-

Testing started at 1:47 AM ...

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dorg.jetbrains.run.directory=/Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/src/test/java/com/framework/features -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=57814:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/target/test-classes:/Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/target/classes:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.13.3/log4j-core-2.13.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.3/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/github/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/3.8.1/webdrivermanager-3.8.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/rauschig/jarchivelib/1.0.0/jarchivelib-1.0.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/commons-compress-1.18.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.11.3/jsoup-1.11.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/6.14.3/testng-6.14.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.72/jcommander-1.72.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache-extras/beanshell/bsh/2.0b6/bsh-2.0b6.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-java/6.1.2/cucumber-java-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-core/6.1.2/cucumber-core-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-gherkin/6.1.2/cucumber-gherkin-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-gherkin-messages/6.1.2/cucumber-gherkin-messages-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/messages/12.1.1/messages-12.1.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/tag-expressions/3.0.0/tag-expressions-3.0.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/10.2.1/cucumber-expressions-10.2.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/datatable/3.3.1/datatable-3.3.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-plugin/6.1.2/cucumber-plugin-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/docstring/6.1.2/docstring-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/html-formatter/6.0.3/html-formatter-6.0.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.0/apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/net/masterthought/cucumber-reporting/5.3.0/cucumber-reporting-5.3.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.10.1/jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.10.1/jackson-annotations-2.10.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.10.1/jackson-core-2.10.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.10.1/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity-engine-core/2.1/velocity-engine-core-2.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.5/joda-time-2.10.5.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.3.0/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/20191001.1/owasp-java-html-sanitizer-20191001.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.10/commons-configuration-1.10.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-testng/6.1.2/cucumber-testng-6.1.2.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59/selenium-java-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/3.141.59/selenium-api-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/3.141.59/selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-edge-driver/3.141.59/selenium-edge-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/3.141.59/selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver/3.141.59/selenium-ie-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-opera-driver/3.141.59/selenium-opera-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/3.141.59/selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/3.141.59/selenium-safari-driver-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/3.141.59/selenium-support-3.141.59.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.8.15/byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/25.0-jre/guava-25.0-jre.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-compat-qual/2.0.0/checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.1.3/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.11.0/okhttp-3.11.0.jar:/Users/keshavmac/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.14.0/okio-1.14.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Users/keshavmac/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/plugins/cucumber-java/lib/cucumber-jvmFormatter.jar:/Users/keshavmac/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/plugins/cucumber-java/lib/cucumber-jvmFormatter5.jar:/Users/keshavmac/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/plugins/cucumber-java/lib/cucumber-jvmFormatter4.jar:/Users/keshavmac/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/plugins/cucumber-java/lib/cucumber-jvmFormatter3.jar io.cucumber.core.cli.Main --plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm5SMFormatter --name ^To test search functionality with blank submit$ --glue com.framework.utils --glue com.framework.stepDef /Users/keshavmac/IdeaProjects/com.CucumberHybrid/src/test/java/com/framework/features/Home.feature
Invoking new Webdriver instance
[INFO ] 2020-08-07 01:47:25.019 [main] BaseSetup - New Webdriver instance invoked
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 46828
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Aug 07, 2020 1:47:26 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
The page title verified is My Store
The validation for mainbanner on homepage has been completed
The validation for search field on homepage has been completed
Closing existing Webdriver instance
[INFO ] 2020-08-07 01:47:38.117 [main] BaseSetup - Webdriver instance closed

    1 Scenarios (1 passed)
    5 Steps (5 passed)
    0m13.865s
    
    
  Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the screenshot of error encountered while opening the log file[image]

Here is the screenshot where I call the logger file.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your class where you drop log messages which you expect to see in the file?

Comment: Did you try configuring the log format ?

Comment: Yes I tried to configure the log format in intellij and also changed the patternlayout in log4js2.properties file. But nothing helped and I was not able to solve this issue

Comment: @AlexeyR. I have posted my class file where I drop the log messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `logger.file.name=Demo` is wrong in your configuration. As per your code the name of logger you are trying to use is fully qualified name of the class.

So you should fix that line to `logger.file.name=com.framework.utils.BaseSetup`. Alternatively (since logger names are hierarchical) you can use `logger.file.name=com.framework` so that all the loggers created for classes of that package would match your configuration.

Comment: I had changed the file according to your answer now data is coming in log file  but Intellij is still showing that error for log format how to resolve that?

Comment: Also can you tell me how I can generate HTML logs for the same log4j configuration?

Comment: I think you need to rise another question(s). It is not really good practice to address new issues within a single question. Open a separate question for html logs (since I have no idea what it is) and separate question for idea view, since I believe it is idea issue, not log4j one.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey for your help and solving my issue. I will raise another question for HTML logs and IDEA View. Is there any way to connect with you on LinkedIn?